# Изменение длины двумерного массива

Tags: c#, массивы

Каким образом можно изменить длину заданного двумерного массива `double[,] arr`?
Учитывая, что для одномерного массива существует метод Array.Resize();

Comment: в чем проблема просто пересоздать массив?

Comment: Он слишком сильно завязан с остальным кодом и используется в других вычислениях

Comment: и в чем тут сложности?

Comment: Слишком много переписывать, +нарушится взаимодействие внутри программы. Самым логичным решением является поиск возможности изменение количества элементов двумерного массива.

Comment: Хотите динамики, используйте коллекции, вы сами себя загнали в тупиковую ситуацию. Массивы же надо пересоздавать, их размет статичен.

Comment: Я вообще не понял о чем речь. Array.Resize() точно также [пересоздаст массив](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,50).

Comment: Если хотите гибкости используйте массив массивов, а не многомерный массив.

Comment: Намекну: в `Array.Resize` используется ref-ссылка на массив. Сделайте точно так же для двумерного массива и вам не придётся ничего переписывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      int[,] arr = new int[10,2]; //создать массив 10x2
      for (int n1 = 0; n1 <= arr.GetUpperBound(0); n1++) {
         arr[n1, 0] = n1;
         arr[n1, 1] = n1 * 2;
      }

      //конвертировать в массив 12x2
      arr = (int[,]) ResizeArray(arr, new int[] { 12, 2} );
      for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= arr.GetUpperBound(0); ctr++)
         Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}", ctr, arr[ctr, 0], arr[ctr, 1]);
      Console.WriteLine();

      //конвертировать в массив 2x2
      arr = (int[,]) ResizeArray(arr, new int[] { 2, 2} );
      for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= arr.GetUpperBound(0); ctr++)
         Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}", ctr, arr[ctr, 0], arr[ctr, 1]);
   }

   private static Array ResizeArray(Array arr, int[] newSizes)
   {
      if (newSizes.Length != arr.Rank)
         throw new ArgumentException("arr must have the same number of dimensions " +
                                     "as there are elements in newSizes", "newSizes");

      var temp = Array.CreateInstance(arr.GetType().GetElementType(), newSizes);
      int length = arr.Length <= temp.Length ? arr.Length : temp.Length;
      Array.ConstrainedCopy(arr, 0, temp, 0, length);
      return temp;
   }
}
```